# NativeScript CLI not creating components

Tags: nativescript-angular

NativeScript CLI not creating any components.

After using the CLI to create an app, I then try to create components, such as  "ng g c test".

Nothing is created.

No information is displayed.

It just returns with the next prompt.

Note that I am able to use the Angular CLI to create components for Angular projects on my machine.

See the following screenshot of what occurs using the NativeScript CLI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  I should use 'tns generate component', not 'ng generate component'